# Composing user interfaces without nesting viewcontrollers

Tags: ios

I am pretty new to IOS but have completed a couple of simple apps.
I have read a number of books, which have helped me getting started, but I am missing som more generel advice on how to best structure an app - especially with regards to UI.

I know this is a very general question, so I will try to put up a specific problem. Suggestions on how to structure this particular app .. or pointers on good reads regarding similar topics would be highly appreciated.

Now the UI of this particular iPad App will look as follows:

The main screen is divided horisontally in two.
Upper two thirds is a sort of canvas / work space
Lower third is a toolbox with various items, which can be dragged to the work space.
The toolbox has different views which holds items in various categories. Lets say: One view with various geometric figures and one wiew with various colors. The user can choose which category to show in the toolbox.
Finally at the top of the screen is a toolbar with a single button.

I am a bit confused as to how to structure my views / ViewControllers. Maybe a lot of my trouble stems from me not fully understanding Apples guideline as to how to use various UI Elements - please feel free to say so if this is the case.

This is how I would start out.
I would construct a main ViewController controlling a main view. The main view would hold the upper toolbar. To this view I would add two subviews. One for the work space and one for the toolbox. The toolbox view confuses me a bit. My idea is making this a tabbed view with one tab for each category of items. However as I understand it, it is bound to cause lots of trouble nesting viewcontrollers which would be the case. Does this imply that using a tabviewcontroller to control only part of the screen is against guidelines? Would it be much better to make up my own 'tabbar' and simply switch between subviews when a tab is tabbed?

Does this also imply, that having a popup view, covering only part of the screen, with a navigationcontroller is equally bad practice? Or would this have to be a modal view? And how about a tableviewcontroller with a view taking up only part of the screen? I fail to see how to accomplish these things without effectively nesting viewcontrollers.

I am sure I got something completely upside down?

Best regards
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting ViewControllers is not a problem.  In fact, View Controller Containment was introduced in iOS 5 to make this even easier.  However, it was still possible before the new containment functions.

The easiest way to nest two ViewControllers is the following:

```
SubViewController *theSubView = [[SubViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:theSubView.view];
```

The subview will then be controlled by the `SubViewController` and will be "nested" in the main ViewController.  (This code would be part of the main ViewController.)

To use the new(er) View Controller Containment methods you will make the `SubViewController` a `childViewController` of the main ViewController.

There is an excellent video from WWDC 2011 that goes over View Controller Containment.  You will need to be a developer to access it [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/).  It is called "Implementing UIViewController Containment."

I would not advise to use the TabBarController in a nested format, it would be easier for you to just build your own view switching method or even use a `UIScrollView` with `pagingEnabled`.

As far as popup views with `NavigationController`s, this is a common practice.  There is nothing wrong with creating a popup with a `NavigationController` inside of it for doing something like, accessing app settings, or configuring a tool from you palette, or accessing saved projects, whatever you can imagine.

I hope this gets you off to a good start.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, Justin. It is very much appreciated! Being in the process of getting familiar with iOS programming, I am very keen on understanding all aspects of the framework, so I will leave this question open just a little longer. I did read about VC containment, and I will probably be okay to restrict my app to IOS5+. I also saw your suggestion on adding af VC's view as a subview numerous places. But I got the impression, that this is against Apple's recommandations: 'A VC controls the entire screen'. Is it valid being concerned about this or am I just to anal about this?

Comment: I think it is better to understand that a VC controls a view, not necessarily the whole screen.  That may have been more of a concern early on with only iPhone and iPod screens, but now there is no reason a VC can't just control a subview of the main view.

Comment: I see. Part of the reason for frowning upon nesting VCs is apparently because device-events - such as rotating - is only sent to the first VC. I guess this is still true so I will have to pass these events on to sub-VCs. Thanks again for taking your time, Justin